How to close a token account when the token is no longer liquid
Closing a token account requires the account balance to be zero, but when that token's liquidity is drained, I cannot then swap that token to bring it to zero balance.


Burn the Tokens
If you hold a large percentage of the token supply and have permission to burn tokens, you can burn the tokens directly from your account. Burning the tokens reduces the supply and the balance in your account, potentially bringing it down to zero. Once the balance is zero, you can close the account.
To burn tokens, you can use the spl-token burn command in the Solana CLI.

Manual Airdrop to Burn Address
If burning isn’t possible or the token is not controlled by you, another option is to send the remaining tokens to a "burn address" (an address that no one controls). This effectively removes the tokens from circulation and reduces your balance to zero.
After transferring the tokens, you can then close the account.

Direct Account Closure Using SPL-Token CLI
If neither of the above options is feasible, you can use the Solana CLI to attempt to force-close the token account. This may involve some costs (like SOL for transaction fees), and it might not be possible in all cases if the balance is not exactly zero
spl-token close <TOKEN_ACCOUNT_ADDRESS>



Your answer solved my question, however can I close that token if it has been frozen?

have never tried closing a frozen token but as far as i understand when a token is frozen no transaction can be performed on that token and burning is considered a transaction so i can only assume it cannot be done
